# How to increment between pages using Selenium and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get my code to increment through the pages of this website and I can't seem to get it to loop and increment, instead doing the first page, and giving up. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
         if(pageExist is not None):
              if(countitup != pageNum):
                 countitup = countitup + 1
                 driver.get('http://800notes.com/Phone.aspx/%s/%s' % (tele800,countitup))
                 delay = 4
                 scamNum = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r"Scam"))
                 spamNum = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r"Call type: Telemarketer"))
                 debtNum = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r"Call type: Debt Collector"))
                 hospitalNum = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r"Hospital"))
                 scamCount = len(scamNum) + scamCount
                 spamCount = len(spamNum) + spamCount
                 debtCount = len(debtNum) + debtCount
                 hospitalCount = len(hospitalNum) + hospitalCount
                 block = soup.find(text=re.compile(r"OctoNet HTTP filter"))
                 extrablock = soup.find(text=re.compile(r"returning an unknown error"))
                 type(block) is str 
                 type(extrablock) is str 
                 if(block is not None or extrablock is not None):
                    print("\n Damn. Gimme an hour to fix this.")
                    time.sleep(2000)
```

Repo: https://github.com/GarnetSunset/Haircuttery/tree/Experimental

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pageExist is not None` this seems to be the problem.
Since it checks whether the page is None and it will most likely never be none.  There is no official way to check for HTTP responses but we can use something like this.

```
if (soup.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/p'[contains(text(),'400')])
#this will check if there's a 400 code in the p tag.
```

or

```
if ('400' in soup.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/p[1]').text)
```

I'm sure there are other ways that one can do this but this is one of those and so that's the only issue here. You can then increment or keep the rest of your code pretty much as soon as you fix the first **if** .

*I might have made some mistakes (syntax) in my code since I'm not testing it but the logic applies), great code tho!*

Also instead of

```
             type(block) is str 
             type(extrablock) is str
```

the pythonic way is using 
[**isinstace**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance)

```
isinstance(block, str)
isinstance(extrablock, str)
```

and as for `time.sleep` you can use [**WebDriverWait**](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) there are two available methods, implicit and explicit wait, please take a look [***here***](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#).

Comment: This is awesome, but, if you take a peek at my code, the "pageExist" variable isn't looking for a 400 error, rather, strings on the page that indicates that there are no comments. I know for a fact it goes into the loop, but, it fails to increment.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, then it's an error outside of this specific code you have provided us,  one within the variables
`if(pageExist is not None):
              if(countitup != pageNum):` Im guessing it has something with this second one, where countitup is always equal to pageNum, I can't pinpoint it but you should check it or provide me with more code or I will take a look later when I'm free, sorry again. Add: Try `countitup == pageNum` see if it executes in the chrome for debugging purposes.

Comment: Now that's the weird part, it does execute, the only part that doesn't work is the incrementing.

Comment: Wow, that means this doesnt execute `driver.get('http://800notes.com/Phone.aspx/%s/%s' % (tele800,countitup))` hmm try `driver.get('http://800notes.com/Phone.aspx/{}/{}/'.format(tele800, countitup))`

Comment: Still not incrementing, and instead doing just one page and going to the next page, unsure why.

Comment: Well that's what it's supposed to do. It does increment, I'm not sure what are you asking. I mean that was your issue it increments through pages, am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Ahh I'm sorry poor sentence structure, its going to the second page, then skipping to the next entry in my excel sheet.

Comment: I mean then the code that you've provided does exactly what it is supposed to do. Maybe someone else can help I'll be